# Dice roll until number is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning javascript and my project requires me to build a webpage that has two dice images, an input box, and a button. After an input is given the button can be pushed and the javascript will tell you how many rolls it took to get that value and the dice images will display that value. My trouble is that I can't get the dice to display the total and I'm not getting the correct number of rolls. It always says that it took 1 roll.

```js
//define a Dice object, properties and methods
var Dice = {
    sides: 6,

    rollDie: function(diceElement) {
        var rolledValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
        var diceImage = this.getURL(rolledValue);
        diceElement.attr("src", diceImage);
    },

    rollDice: function() {
       var diceTotal = 0;
       diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice1'));
       diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice2'));
       return diceTotal;
    },

    rollDoubles: function(n) {
       var die1 = 0;
       var die2 = 0;
       var numRolls = 0;
        do {
            die1 = this.rollDie($('#dice1'));
            die2 = this.rollDie($('#dice2'));
            numRolls++;
        } while(!(die1 == die2 && die1 == n));
        return numRolls;
    },

    URL_prefix: "http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/",

    getURL: function(n) {
        //return the URL for an n-dot die
        return this.URL_prefix + "die" + n + ".gif";
    }
};

//top-level function
function roll_number(n) {
  var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var dicetotal = die1 + die2;
  var numRolls = 0;
    //roll two dice until you hit n
  do {
      die1 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1'));
      die2 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
      numRolls++;
  } while(dicetotal == n);  
  return numRolls;
    //return the number of rolls
}

function getRoll () {
  var number = parseFloat($("#num").val());
  var numRolls = roll_number(number);
  $("#time").text( "You rolled " + number + " in " + 
    numRolls + " rolls");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#R").on("click", getRoll);
  //$("#roll").on("click", Dice.getURL);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dice-namic</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Dice-namic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Roll Number</h2>
    <img id="dice1" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <img id="dice2" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <p>Enter target number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="num">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="R">Roll 'em!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="time">Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//define a Dice object, properties and methods
var Dice = {
    sides: 6,

    rollDie: function(diceElement) {
        var rolledValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
        var diceImage = this.getURL(rolledValue);
        diceElement.attr("src", diceImage);
        return rolledValue;//added this line;
    },

    rollDice: function() {
       var diceTotal = 0;
       diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice1'));
       diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice2'));
       return diceTotal;
    },

    rollDoubles: function(n) {
       var die1 = 0;
       var die2 = 0;
       var numRolls = 0;
        do {
            die1 = this.rollDie($('#dice1'));
            die2 = this.rollDie($('#dice2'));
            numRolls++;
        } while(!(die1 == die2 && die1 == n));
        return numRolls;
    },

    URL_prefix: "http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/",

    getURL: function(n) {
        //return the URL for an n-dot die
        return this.URL_prefix + "die" + n + ".gif";
    }
};

//top-level function
function roll_number(n) {
  var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var dicetotal = die1 + die2;
  var numRolls = 0;
    //roll two dice until you hit n
  do {
      die1 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1'));
      die2 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
      dicetotal=die1+die2;//added this line
      numRolls++;
  } while(dicetotal != n);  //modified
  return numRolls;
    //return the number of rolls
}

function getRoll () {
  var number = parseFloat($("#num").val());
  var numRolls = roll_number(number);
  $("#time").text( "You rolled " + number + " in " + 
    numRolls + " rolls");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#R").on("click", getRoll);
  //$("#roll").on("click", Dice.getURL);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dice-namic</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Dice-namic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Roll Number</h2>
    <img id="dice1" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <img id="dice2" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <p>Enter target number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="num">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="R">Roll 'em!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="time">Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have modified the code. you are not returning the value that came after dice is played. use negation for while loop. you are not changing the total value.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `roll_number`:

```
function roll_number(n) {
  var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Dice.sides) + 1;
  var dicetotal = die1 + die2;
  var numRolls = 0;
  do {
      die1 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1'));
      die2 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
      dicetotal = die1 + die2;  // and recalculate dicetotal here
      numRolls++;
  } while(dicetotal == n);  // this should be while(dicetotal != n)
  return numRolls;
}
```

also in `Dice.rollDie` you should `return rolledValue` at the end.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried the "!=" and that caused my page to crash

Comment: @zgarcia see my update, there is one more thing missing

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. Starting with the `roll_number` function, the `dicetotal` doesn't get recalculated in the do while loop.  Secondly, the condition that would take you out of the loop is when `dicetotal == n`.  You actually want the opposite: loop while `dicetotal` is different than the `n` you are trying to roll.  Finally, the `rollDie` function will change the displayed image, but it won't return you the rolled value.

`rollDie` should be like:

```
 rollDie: function(diceElement) {
     var rolledValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
     var diceImage = this.getURL(rolledValue);
     diceElement.attr("src", diceImage);
     return rolledValue;
 }
```

and `roll_number` should be like this:

```
function roll_number(n) {
  var dicetotal; //No need to set a total as the first total will be done in the loop
  var numRolls = 0;
  do {
      dicetotal = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1')) + Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
      numRolls++;
  } while(dicetotal != n);  
  return numRolls;
}
```